# How to convert raw PCM data to a valid WAV file with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion, wav, ffprobe, pcm

I run this command: `ffmpeg -f f32le -i pipe:0 -f wav pipe:1`

```
ffmpeg version 4.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, f32le, from 'pipe:0':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32le, 44100 Hz, mono, flt, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_f32le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Output #0, wav, to 'pipe:1':
Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 pcm_s16le
size=   15144kB time=00:02:55.82 bitrate= 705.6kbits/s speed= 352x    
size=   30684kB time=00:05:56.24 bitrate= 705.6kbits/s speed= 356x    
size=   32043kB time=00:06:12.01 bitrate= 705.6kbits/s speed= 354x    
video:0kB audio:32042kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000238%
```

Where `pipe:0` is the raw PCM data of the left channel of [this file](https://ufile.io/ywt0a7yu). Here is the [output wav](https://ufile.io/x1ef0ka3).

The output seems to be semi valid. It won't play in Quicktime or iTunes. When attempting to add it to an Ableton project, I get "output.wav could not be read. It may be corrupt or not licensed."

However, it does play fine if I simply drag the output wav in Chrome.

The ffprobe output confirms some sort of problem with the file. For this command:

`ffprobe -loglevel verbose /Users/maximedupre/Desktop/Dropbox/Programming/api/gg.wav`

```
ffprobe version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[wav @ 0x7f81e3004a00] Ignoring maximum wav data size, file may be invalid
[wav @ 0x7f81e3004a00] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[wav @ 0x7f81e3004a00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, wav, from '/Users/maximedupre/Desktop/Dropbox/Programming/api/gg.wav':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Duration: 00:06:12.01, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

How can I modify my ffmpeg command to produce a valid wav file?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg can't update metadata in WAVE files when output is written over a non-seekable protocol like a pipe. Quicktime seems to rely on metadata to determine file validity. You have to write to file or some other seekable protocol.

```
ffmpeg -f f32le -i pipe:0 -f wav file-out.wav
```

BTW, your input is stereo, so it should be

```
ffmpeg -f f32le -channels 2 -i pipe:0 -f wav file-out.wav
```

Comment: This seems to be correct. I'm trying to find official documentation for this, are you aware of some? Thanks!

Comment: Many muxers which store metadata have limitations with non-seekable output. Not explicitly documented, but may be a good idea. Will look into it.